# No building and Point of interest available while setting up "Rendering Osm Data Ubuntu using MAPSERVER"

Tags: openstreetmap, mapserver, ubuntu

I have followed [RenderingOsmDataUbuntu 10.10](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataUbuntu) and set up Google styled web map using **mapserver**. The **osm-google.map** seems to be **not** using table **osm_new_buildings**. Also **no** POI (Point of interest) data is seems to be imported from the OSM file. How can I add both?

Comment: I guess most people use the official mapnik based rendering stack (http://switch2osm.org) to create OSM webmaps. If possible, it might be worth to use this one instead, as you can get more support. Also you might ask at http://help.osm.org as the focus there is OSM

Comment: Hmm.. But I am already editing/updating the POSTGIS tables (imported using IMPOSM) with additional data(where it is missed in OSM)

Comment: Have you considered adding the missing data to OSM itself? Also, be aware that if you are altering the existing OSM data you must [make it available](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright) under the [ODbL](http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/summary/).

Comment: @HommeZwaagstra Actually I am adding some information which are not useful for public, like some custom points(with order numbers), some road buffers as geofence, polygons as private route identifiers and some private vehicle stops(as polygonal area). These features may not be useful for others and virtually damage the quality if I uploaded the same. My main aim is to retain the map drawn using a google style. Please share your thought.

Comment: @mapsir I can see why you may not want to add some of this data to OSM. Regarding the licencing issues you may want to discuss your use case on the [legal-talk](http://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/legal-talk) mailing list and investigate the [Open Data License](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Open_Data_License) wiki page.

Comment: @HommeZwaagstra Thank you. But can you please go through my question and try to give an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The "google" style does not render buildings by default, you can add it by editing generate_style.py and setting display_buildings to 1 in the google variable (https://github.com/mapserver/basemaps/blob/master/generate_style.py#L1122).

For pois, there are none added by default aside from place names, you'll have to add them yourself to the mapfiles (adding a layer in places.map very similar to the "places" layer is the way to go).

Comment: But, I can't see any tables with POI/Point data in the ImpOSM extracted DB.

Comment: there are a few in the amenities table. you'll have to create your own poi table with the categories you need if you want more, have a look at https://bitbucket.org/stvn/imposm/src/8303b88da99f6feaf48b62ed71affccdf6d4cc41/imposm/defaultmapping.py for a few ideas

Comment: Can I import the whole POI data from .osm into a new table in the same DB. Because the amenities table doesn't seems to have the whole POIs. If yes, how? Using ImpOSM/osm2pgsql? & Will that affect the existing DB?

Comment: Is it possible to render POIs/landmarks using google Map like icons? Any readily available icon sets?